# PDFsharp: place text according to PdfPage.Rotate

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I'm trying to add footer text to each pdf page using PDFsharp library. And it works pretty well using `XGraphics` and this code:

```
gfx.DrawString(footerText, font, XBrushes.Blue, new XPoint(10, newPage.Height - 10));
```

Until I get pdfs with pages where `Rotate` parameter is not `0`:

[Footer Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8iRE.png)

Of course, all footers should be in the left bottom corner. I've tried to use

```
gfx.RotateTransform(-newPage.Rotate);
```

But I'm not sure which coordinates should I use. I think, that it should be a simple way to place footer at the bottom left corner for each situation. Does anybody know it?

Answer (score 0):

I handled it with this workaround:

```
// offset from left bottom corner = 10
int rotateAngle = 0;
XPoint point = new XPoint(10, newPage.Height - 10);

// Rotate text, if page is rotated
switch (newPage.Rotate)
{
    case PAGE_ROTATION_090: // Rotate = 90
        rotateAngle = -newPage.Rotate;
        point = new XPoint(10-newPage.Height, newPage.Height-10);
        break;
    case PAGE_ROTATION_270: // Rotate = 270
        rotateAngle = -newPage.Rotate;
        point = new XPoint(10 + newPage.Height-newPage.Width, -10);
        break;
}

gfx.RotateTransform(rotateAngle);
gfx.DrawString(footerText, font, XBrushes.Blue, point);
```

But I'm pretty sure, there should be more elegant solution.